# Does not work location history in embedded application: ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a large application in which want implement a part of the functional on Ember js.
There is some page which is located on this path `/item/item_id_here/profile/documents` 
Only documents must be Ember app.
I create new ember project with ember cli. And include to documents page in my base project vendor.js and ember.js where router is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('test');
});

Router.reopen({
    location: 'history'
});


export default Router;
```

When I run the application in the console displays an error

```
UnrecognizedURLError: /item/item_id_here/profile/documents
```

When i try change:

```
Router.reopen({
    location: 'hash'
});
```

Everything works well.

I'm a little worked with Ember so I started to think that my situation is normal. But I decided to double-check and include ember to my basic project directly without ember cli etc. For example:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#ember-app'
});

App.Router.reopen({
    location: 'history'
});


App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('test');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
       alert( 'index' ); 
    }
});

App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        alert( 'test' );
    }
});
```

I was discouraged but everything worked as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the `baseURL` for the ember app. Place the following in `config\environment.js`, restart `ember-cli` and you should be good to go.

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
    var ENV = {
        environment: environment,
        baseURL: '/item/item_id_here/profile/documents/'
```

See the [instructions here](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#history-api-and-base-url) for how to deploy to a URL that isn't the root in the Ember CLI guides.